# DateTime equivalent in C

Tags: c++, datetime

I'm trying to adapt a .Net code snippet to good-old C without pulling in masses of C++.Net classes.  It looks something like this:

```
  Int64 ticks = DateTime.Now.ToBinary();

  WriteSigned64(address, ticks);
```

Is there an equivalent in C/C++ compiled for a Win32 process?  The only things I've found use alternative and somewhat limited 32 bit structs.   I also have to write this field to be compatible with the .Net version.

Comment: C or C++? Your title says C, your question says C/C++, your tag says C++.

Comment: It's called Win32 for a reason: it was made for 32-bit systems (and languages that might not have a 64-bit data type).  If there's a 64-bit number to be had, you'll almost certainly have to deal with retrieving it as a struct containing a pair of 32-bit numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for a .NET library?  There is nothing in the **standard C++ library** that handles a Win32 process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `time_t time(time_t *t);`, declared in `time.h`. It gives you the number of seconds from the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)).

`time_t` in all *reasonably recent* version is a 64 bits integer.

It is a C function, but it can be called from a C++ program.

Comment: And to convert to `DateTime`-compatible tick numbers, multiply by `10000000` and add `621355968000000000`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any direct way of doing what you asked and still have it perform the exact same as the code you provided.

`DateTime.ToBinary()` is not just the ticks.  It encodes both the `Ticks` and the `Kind` properties of the `DateTime` object into a single binary value.  Refer to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx).  You may also wish to refer to the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs).

To illustrate, consider the following C# code:

```csharp
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.Kind);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToBinary());
```

Sample Output:

```
Local
635476072989775339
-8587895711865000469
```

You should also recognize that `DateTime.Now` returns a `Local` kind, which means the ticks are based on the local time zone of the computer the code is running on.  If you take the ticks (or binary) from one system and recreate a `DateTime` on a system with a different time zone, you will get a different value than you originally encoded.

By contrast, `time_t` and most other time related types in C/C++ are based on UTC, so there is no ambiguity in the value.